# Change cart subtotal in cartthrob using hook

Tags: cartthrob, hook

I've set up the `cartthrob_pre_process` hook to look something like this:

```
public function cartthrob_pre_process($data)
{
    $data['subtotal'] = 500.00;
}
```

It then goes to PayPal, which is the selected gateway. But when I get there it's showing the old price. Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be using a different hook?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you should be able to do this:

```
ee()->cartthrob->cart->set_subtotal(500);
```

Or you may have to change the total to effect the price sent to PayPal:

```
ee()->cartthrob->cart->set_total(500);
```